# Erroneous "no longer accepting answers"... Or?

Tags: discussion, status-review, error-message

Recently when I attempted adding an answer to my own question I got the "we are no longer accepting answers from your account..." error message when attempting to post. I'm fairly sure my answer quality is decent, yet all info on the topic indicates that this is not a temporary thing.

I made another attempt posting, and then got a more generic error message.

Finally I refreshed and went through the answer procedure again, and this time I got the "human check" before being able to post without issues.

I'm assuming this was a temporary error...? Seems odd that I got the error when the information describing it indicates that this is very much a permanent error state for most that get the error.

Screenshot of when the error was received, and heart skipped a beat:

[image: Answer ban error message]

Related question/answer: [Maven git describe without tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74247538/maven-git-describe-without-tags)

Help center reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans

Comment: A SO mod could verify this, but there's no way you're answer banned. Answer bans are for people who are brand new to the site (or at least *extremely* low rep) and whose only activity is to post downvoted answers (or maybe also downvoted questions). I would guess that this message was accidentally chosen as a sort of default and you're actually having problems with [Cloudflare](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloudflare).

Comment: You don't happen to have hundreds to thousands of downvoted deleted answers to compensate for the upvoted ones, right?

Comment: Are you on a work domain or using a shared device? It *could* be that there's someone else who is on the network, or has used the device, that has contributed a large amount of bad material and that's effected your ability to post from your current location. Though I *thought* 20k users were "immune" to such things.

Comment: I don't have many downvoted or deleted answers. That would be a special kind of edge case! I am however at a work domain behind a proxy. I wouldn't expect there to be many "spammers" here, but I can't really say.

Comment: This account is not banned from answering.

Comment: Maybe they are out of 20K slots so they block anyone from reaching that milestone. if only Jon Skeet would give up his spot ...